# Filling out contact phone on paypal

Tags: paypal, contacts, phone-number

I have a strange problem.... I'm trying to filling out all data in Paypal request but all fields works execpt contact phone. This is my code:

```
<form name="f" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="7.91" /><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://localhost/ipn.php?idB=37" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@123.it" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Acquisto Prodotti" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/sexy/thank_you_page.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost/" /><input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="John" />
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Doe" />
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="Viale cattaneo, 23" />
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="Roma" /><input type="hidden" name="state" value="Siracusa" /><input type="hidden" name="zip" value="91230" /><input type="hidden" name="country" value="IT" />
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="italy" />
<input type="hidden" name="country_code" value="IT" />
<input type="hidden" name="contact_phone" value="1234567" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="me@me.com" />
<input type="submit" value="Click here if you are not redirected within 10 seconds" />
</form>
```

I read here but nothing help
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Someone knows how to SET Contact Phone?

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8QUF.png).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following fields:

- night_phone_a
- night_phone_b
- night_phone_c

These fields, in the US, shall be used to indicate the number format AAA-BBB-CCC. For other parts of the world, just put everything into night_phone_a.

And BTW, you have visited the right document page. These 3 fields are on the page.

Comment: Hi, Thanks I fixed. You must put at limit 2 fileds, if you put only one (night_phone_a) doesn't work... In Italy i putted prefix (+39) in night_phone_a and phone number on night_phone_b

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I used these fields a long time ago and I forgot the details. Just remembered they could be used.